# Rewrite rule - how to exclude only single depth?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

in my functions.php I have rewrite rule which excludes string starting with numbers (if I understand it right) so now if I have link $slug/123anything/ it excludes it - code:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
        "^$slug/(?![\d]+\-)(.+)$",
        'index.php?post_type=xxx',
        'top'
    );
```

But what I would need is same rule that excludes only single string/folder depth - example if link is $slug/anything/ or $slug/123anything/ - it should be excluded but if link is $slug/anything/anything or $slug/anything/anything/... then it should rewrite.

I tried this code and some variations but no luck

```
add_rewrite_rule(
        "^$slug/(?!(\w+)/?$)(.+)$",
        'index.php?post_type=xxx',
        'top'
    );
```

I also tried code, which works but not in all cases - when I have single query after first string/folder depth ( $slug/anything/anything ) it is not working ok, but if I have two or more depths ($slug/anything/anything/anything...) it works fine.

```
add_rewrite_rule(
        "^$slug/(?![.+]/$)(.+)/(.+)$",
        'index.php?post_type=xxx',
        'top'
    );
```

If it helps - urls that should be rewritten have query strings and always end with numbers (no / on the end). So maybe good way would be to try not to exclude but to rewrite only if link has query sting or ends with number without "/".

I would be grateful for any help and advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it can help someone with similar problem I found solution in a way to check if a URL contains a query string and if yes then apply rewrite rule and in my case it works perfect.

```
if ($_GET){
add_rewrite_rule(
        "^$slug/(.+)$",
        'index.php?post_type=xxx',
        'top'
    );
}
```